# Creating an expression within a SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, expression

I am working on building a database application for the company that I work for, and while I have most of the SQL done for a specific query, there is one part that is eluding me.

The object of this query is to pull a list of open work orders and to display how much of the job has been completed through two different processes (the clean room and being boxed). The SQL statement below successfully pulls up all of the open work orders and the quantities that are associated with the specific jobs. What I need to do is create two more columns - one that shows the percentage of the CEA complete (ceaQty/(WO.startQty*Standards.BOX)), and the other showing the percentage of the Boxing complete (boxQty/WO.StartQty). Are there any ideas on how I can do this?

```
SELECT  dbo.WO.WO, 
    WO.WorkOrderNumber, 
    WO.StartQty, 
    WO.Assembly, 
    Standards.[Mfg Family], 
    Standards.BOX,
    (SELECT SUM(ScanData.Quantity) 

        FROM
            ScanData
        WHERE
            (ScanData.Task = 'CEA' AND (WO.WorkOrderNumber = ScanData.WorkOrderNumber))
    ) AS ceaQty,
    (SELECT SUM(ScanData.Quantity)
        FROM
            ScanData    
        WHERE
            (ScanData.Task = 'Boxing' AND (Wo.WorkOrderNumber = ScanData.WorkOrderNumber))
    ) AS boxQty

FROM  
    Standards 
    INNER JOIN WO ON Standards.Product = WO.Assembly

WHERE       
     WO.Status != 'C' AND
     WO.WO LIKE '00%' AND
    (WO.Assembly LIKE '%SII%' OR WO.Assembly LIKE '%SWW%' )
ORDER BY 
    WO DESC, 
    Standards.[Mfg Family] DESC;
```

This is not a database that I designed or created, but is one that I inherited, and I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can always be done via a nested SQL statement.  you take the query with things like max, min, etc and nest it inside so it can behave like normal data.

The order by has to be on the outside in this case.

I'm surprised your original query doesn't have a group by on these columns - dbo.WO.WO, 
    WO.WorkOrderNumber, 
    WO.StartQty, 
    WO.Assembly, 
    Standards.[Mfg Family], 
    Standards.BOX,

but that would go on the inner query also.

```
select c.*, (c.ceaQty/(c.startQty*c.BOX)) calccolumn1, (c.boxQty/c.StartQty) calccolumn2
from
(SELECT  dbo.WO.WO, 
    WO.WorkOrderNumber, 
    WO.StartQty, 
    WO.Assembly, 
    Standards.[Mfg Family], 
    Standards.BOX,
    (SELECT SUM(ScanData.Quantity) 

        FROM
            ScanData
        WHERE
            (ScanData.Task = 'CEA' AND (WO.WorkOrderNumber = ScanData.WorkOrderNumber))
    ) AS ceaQty,
    (SELECT SUM(ScanData.Quantity)
        FROM
            ScanData    
        WHERE
            (ScanData.Task = 'Boxing' AND (Wo.WorkOrderNumber = ScanData.WorkOrderNumber))
    ) AS boxQty

FROM  
    Standards 
    INNER JOIN WO ON Standards.Product = WO.Assembly

WHERE       
     WO.Status != 'C' AND
     WO.WO LIKE '00%' AND
    (WO.Assembly LIKE '%SII%' OR WO.Assembly LIKE '%SWW%' )
) c
ORDER BY 
    c.WO DESC, 
    c.[Mfg Family] DESC
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for the Assist! I'm a SQL rookie, so you just taught me something.

Comment: glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

...or you could use a CTE, as this is easier to follow imho:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT  dbo.WO.WO, 
        WO.WorkOrderNumber, 
        WO.StartQty, 
        WO.Assembly, 
        Standards.[Mfg Family], 
        Standards.BOX,
        (SELECT SUM(ScanData.Quantity) 

            FROM
                ScanData
            WHERE
                (ScanData.Task = 'CEA' AND (WO.WorkOrderNumber = ScanData.WorkOrderNumber))
        ) AS ceaQty,
        (SELECT SUM(ScanData.Quantity)
            FROM
                ScanData    
            WHERE
                (ScanData.Task = 'Boxing' AND (Wo.WorkOrderNumber = ScanData.WorkOrderNumber))
        ) AS boxQty

    FROM  
        Standards 
        INNER JOIN WO ON Standards.Product = WO.[Assembly]
    WHERE       
         WO.Status != 'C' AND
         WO.WO LIKE '00%' AND
        (WO.Assembly LIKE '%SII%' OR WO.Assembly LIKE '%SWW%' ))
SELECT
    *,
    ceaQty / startQty * BOX AS cea_percent,
    boxQty / SstartQty AS box_percent
FROM
    x
ORDER BY 
    WO DESC, 
    [Mfg Family] DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked as well as the previous answer did. So for anyone looking at a similar type of question, both of these solutions worked out very well!